# Neural network classifies everything into one class, recall=1 on imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to do a binary classification with a Deep Neural Network (esp. VGG16) in Keras. Unfortunately I have a very imbalanced data-set (15.000/1.800 images) but just can't find a way to circumvent that..

**Results that I'm seeing** 
(on training and validation data)

- Recall = `1`
- Precision = `0.1208` (which is exactly the ratio between class `0` and class `1` samples)
- AUC = `0.88` (after ~30 epochs with SGD, which seems to be `1 - Precision`)

**What I've done**

- Switching from loss/accuracy metrics to AUC with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527423/1381666) little helper
- Utilizing `class_weight` like described [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18722) which doesn't seem to help
- Trying different optimizers (SGD, Adam, RMSProp)
- Adding `BatchNormalization` layers to my (untrained) VGG16 and set `use_bias` to `False` on Convolutional Layers. **See my whole network as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/wottpal/deb90512d5ceab0b9d8b4778d5125faf).**
- Doing Augmentation to enlarge dataset with Keras inbuilt `ImageDataGenerator`.

**What I think could help further** (but did not try yet)

1. Doing more data augmentation for one class than the other. Unfortunately I'm using one `ImageDataGenerator` for my whole training data and I don't know how to augment one class more than the other.
2. Maybe a custom loss-function which penalises false decisions more? How would I implement that? Currently I'm just using `binary_crossentropy`.
3. Theoretically I could adjust the class-membership-threshold for prediction but that doesn't help with training and would not improve the result, right?
4. Maybe decrease batch-size like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38668141/1381666). But I don't really see why that should help. Currently I'm determining the batch-size programmatically to show all the training and validation data to the network in one epoch:

   `steps_per_epoch = int(len(train_gen.filenames) / args.batch_size)
   validation_steps = int(len(val_gen.filenames) / args.batch_size)`

What do you think should I tackle first or do you have a better idea? I'm also glad for every help with implementation details.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to prepare class-balanced batches ( includes doublings of class 1 ) like described in https://community.rstudio.com/t/ensure-balanced-mini-batches-while-training/7505 ( R Studio ). Also read [Neural Network - Working with a imbalanced dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664487/neural-network-working-with-a-imbalanced-datasetand) and [balancing an imbalanced dataset with keras image generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648129/balancing-an-imbalanced-dataset-with-keras-image-generator)

Another possibility is to perform feature extraction in the pre-processing meaning letting run image processing algorithms over the images to highlight characteristic features