# What is the correct way to penalize one prediction more over another?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function, transformer-model, cross-entropy

I have a BERT-based sequence classification model that takes as an input 4 strings and out 2 labels for each one:

```
my_input = [string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4]
out_logits = model(my_input).logits
out_softmax = torch.softmax(out_logits)
out_softmax 
>>> tensor([[0.8666, 0.1334],
        [0.8686, 0.1314],
        [0.8673, 0.1327],
        [0.8665, 0.1335]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward0>)
```

My loss function is `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` and my labels are tensors with indices corresponding to the correct labels: `tensor([0., 0., 0., 1.])`. Note that every label except for one is `1`.

```
loss = loss_fun(out_softmax, labels_tensor)
# step
optim.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optim.step()
```

The issue I'm having as appearing above, is that the model learns to just predict one class (e.g., the first column above). Not entirely sure why it's happening, but I thought that penalizing more the prediction that should be `1` might help.

How can I penalize more that prediction?

Comment: You can always try to calculate the class weights and adding it as a parameter to the loss function, but from my experience this doesn't really work THAT effectively and 99% of the time balancing out the data is better. Is your data imbalanced? What's the ratio of 0:1?

Comment: `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` expects unnormalised logits as input, so you should pass `out_logits` rather than `out_softmax` to `loss_fun`. On data imbalance, it’s maybe better to check Cross Validated instead, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a weight tensor (one weight for each class) to the constructor of [nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) to get such a weighting:

> Parameters:
>
> weight (Tensor, optional) – a manual rescaling weight given to each class. If given, has to be a Tensor of size C

where `C` is the number of classes.

But you should also think about alternatives, see the comment of @Sean above or e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664487/neural-network-working-with-a-imbalanced-dataset).